# Linked lists and references

Tags: linked-list

list-->[-1-]<-->[-2-]<-->[-3-]<-->[-4-]<-->[-5-]

The above diagram is a circular doubly linked list of 5 nodes, and "list" is a reference/pointer to the first node.The last node, 5, and the fist node, 1, reference one another, as this list is circular, but I couldn't depict that diagrammatically.

Does the assignment

list.next.next.next =list.prev

on the above list modify it into the list

list-->[-1-]<-->[-2-]<-->[-3-]<-->[-5-]?

EDIT:

This isn't homework. I'm going over exercises in a textbook for self study. The book doesn't provide answers, so I decided to ask here.

Comment: Operations on lists are better understood if tested with a real program in some programming language, so that you have a precise definition of the data structure in terms of variables, pointers, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it is double linked, to create an other, valid, doubly-linked list, you have to update at least one next and one prev link (in the general case). as you update only one next link, it can not create what you show, as this is a valid example.

`3.next` would be `5`, but `5.prev` would still be `4`.

Comment: @Gabriel i am pretty sure it is `2.next`. start from `list` and count the `->` arrows to the right; the 3rd one is the one getting changed. as Renzo said in a comment on the question, it is easier to see when you actually write the code and check there.

Comment: list isn't a node. It's a pointer. It doesn't have a next variable. The first next variable is at node one, the second at node 2, and the third at node 3, and hence the third's gets updated, no?

Comment: ahh ok. that is also a valid way of interpreting it, i agree. i would say both ways are valid, or say: the question is not concrete enough to answer that. again, this confusion could be evaded when actually using code. either way, the important conclusion stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

No. It will "mess" things up quite a bit though.

Since your only changing one end of the connection between 2 -> 3, and the value you set it to us undefined (list.prev), it will create a broken list where 2 no longer points to anything meaningful. You could fix it though, since having a circular doubly linked list will allow you to "go backwards" from 1 -> 5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 and fix the pointers